# Call ajax load from a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to dynamically load html into a popup using ajax with this:

`$('body').load( new_url, function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest ) { ... } );`

It works fine, but it doesn't load the html into the subwindow, it loads it into the opening window. If I have a reference to the subwindow "win", how can I do something like this:

`win.$( 'body' ).load...`

currently, that gives an error saying `win.$ is not a function`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead ::

```
$("body", win.document).load(URL, function() {
    // do your stuff
});
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: @ATOzTOA, what about the second one

Answer (score 0):

You should use it like this:

```
$('body', win.document).load...
```